# Accessing an array element inside a struct (which is part of an array of structs) (in C)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I want to create an array of structs, though the no. of structs in the array is read from a file / input from user.

I declare a struct:

```
struct student{
    char name[16];
    int *available;
    int sum;
};

typedef struct student ST;
```

I allocate memory for the array of structs (after getting the input of size):

```
ptr = (ST*)calloc(lines, sizeof(ST));
```

I also allocate space for each array in each struct (using a loop):

```
ptr->available = (int*)calloc(lines, sizeof(int));
```

NOW - I want to put values in these arrays. How do I reach each element?

I tried:

```
*((ptr+i)->(available+j)) = 1;
```

But the compiler tells me: `error: expected identifier before ‘(’`
(i and j are indexes I use, i for the i'th struct, and j for the j'th element of the array).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using array index notation for readability:

`ptr[i].available[j] = 1;`

(The equivalent syntax using explicit pointer arithmetic is the considerably more obfuscated `*((ptr + i)->available + j) = 1;`)

Answer (score 1):

Forget the `*(ptr + idx)` notation; it's used to confuse beginners, not in 'real code'.  However, if you must use it, then:

```
*((ptr+i)->available+j) = 1;
```

But use:

```
ptr[i].available[j] = 1;
```